# Machine learning & Nerual Network How to chosen the method?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I'm writing a paper comparing ML & NN. However, in one of the question it asked to justify the method that you picked and the hyperparameter.

I was thinking of writing in general are there any r code implementation that i could test to help justify my answer.?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I would recommend that you justify your methodology in the paper by saying what your rationale was for picking the methodology that you picked.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperparameters should be chosen to optimize the metrics that you're using. In general, you can look for some searching techniques or genetic algorithm, both are available in R. But the optimization problem of choosing hyperparameters is in general nonconvex. It means that the set of hyperparameters you picked might be different from what are suggested from automatic methods, but both could lead to similar values.